# Node.js installation stuck ona line of code

Tags: node.js, installation

I am halfway in the install progress of Node.js, but after it started to install all the other packages (after the command prompt verification part) it gets stuck on the line `Created a UnelevatedInstallerTelemetryDecorator` should I let it continue to run or just kill it?

note: I have been stuck on that line for 20 minutes now

Comment: Was it ever solved?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Definitely let it run. Mine took about 15 minutes and ended successfully.

Comment: Thanks...stuck in the same place was thinking to close it, but saw this I decided to wait. After waited for like 5 minutes and it went through...so just need to be patient..

Comment: same here.... don't know how long it took but eventually it continued...

Comment: I can't believe I am here again with exactly the same issue... at least I know I should wait again....

Comment: only that this time i did look at the time, it took it 15 min. to continue from this "looks like I am dead and stuck and will never continue" state.