# Node.js installation stuck in power shell

Tags: javascript, node.js, powershell, visual-studio-code, installation

I tried to install node.js and the power shell got stuck at this line::
Created a UnelevatedInstallerTelemetryDecorator

I closed the power shell and ran the installation package >> clicked on repair >> it finished installation but didn't open power shell nor cmd.

I am able to load node.js in my vscode now.... Is that ok??

Comment: The installation isn't stuck, it just takes from 20 to 30 minutes to run on some (~slow) machines, be patient.

Comment: FYI, same question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68614500/node-js-installation-stuck-ona-line-of-code , accepted answer is to just wait and let it keep running.

Answer (score 0):

**Why not use Chocolatey? Do you know this tool? Maybe it doesn't suit your needs?**

Chocolatey allows you to install software in just a few command lines from PowerShell.

*All you have to do is use*

```
choco install nodejs
```

Comment: Maybe a bit heavy on the first line of the answer ;-) Not everyone knows of, wants to use chocolatey or can use it of course, but in essence your answer may be a valid alternative.

Comment: Yes indeed there can be many reasons why someone would not want to use this tool, but this is a good alternative, assuming that the user who created this post did not know this tool.

Comment: The powershell the OP mentioned is indeed using chocolatey to install nodejs, so this is not an answer. Nodejs on windows is known to get stuck while downloading and installing packages with chocolatey.